# How to find a string inside the <td> tag in HTML and show?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to click an respective image button with respect to  that having certain string.For example lets assume I've two values in

- task1 job1
- task2 job2

and there is a button for each task.Now I want to auto click on the button that the  having "task1" text.

[image: Image of my sample table]

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {                         
    var foundin = $('*tr td:contains("task1")');
    var objs = JSON.stringify(foundin);               
    if (objs != null) {                       
      $('#imageField2').trigger('click');                                                                                                                            
      alert("Found!!!");  
    }
  });              
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Task</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>task1 job1</td>
      <td><input type="image"  id="imageField"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>task2 job2</td>
      <td><input type="image"  id="imageField2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Also I need to get the value "task1" from ***var foundin***

*Note:There is an function for timeout for button click*

```
setTimeout(function () {
  location = ''
}, 3000)
```

Comment: You have a `$(function() {...}` _inside_ a `$(document).ready(function(){...}`. These do exactly the same thing, and one of them is redundant. What is the purpose of the `JSON.stringify()` call? How does JSON relate to what you're trying to do? You're testing the result of `JSON.stringify()` to see if it is `null` (and since it's using `!=` it will also test for `undefined`). When do you expect to see a `null` result from `JSON.stringify()`? The value you're passing into `JSON.stringify()` is a jQuery object, so the result is never `null`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary - Yeah, I understood. I'm very basic to jquery.I'll keep in mind always.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery `.each()` function for this..

```js
$('tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){
  var foundin = $(this).html();
  if(foundin.indexOf('task1') !== -1) { 
    console.log('task1 string found');
    $(this).parents('tr').find('input').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>Task</td>
      <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>task1 job1</td>
      <td><input type="image"  id="imageField"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>task2 job2</td>
      <td><input type="image"  id="imageField2"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

> var foundin = $('*tr td:contains("task1")');

with (remove the '*')

> var foundin = $('tr td:contains("task1")');

as for the value, use:

```
if(foundin.length == 1){
   var text = foundin.text();
   // do your thing...
}
```